# Android: how to find application locking xtables?

Tags: iptables

I have Pixel Experience (Android 10) installed on my Redmi K20. + Magisk 21.4.
In terminal I enter command `iptables -t mangle -L -n | grep TTL` which throws `Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?`. How to find the this application? Or how to drop xtables lock?

Answer (score 2):

`/system/bin/iptables` binary [holds](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iptables/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/iptables/xshared.c#280) an advisory [lock](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) on [`/system/etc/xtables.lock`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iptables/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/config.h#86) file (which is usually [`/run/xtables.lock`](http://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/configure.ac?h=v1.8.7#n74) on normal Linux distros).

It's the native `netd` service which performs operations with NetFilter but on a rooted device normal apps (e.g. AFWall+) may also execute the binary to add or remove firewall rules.

Use the [`lslocks`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lslocks.8.html) command to list all the system locks currently held and the applications holding them. Or read the `/proc/locks` file directly.

You should not try to drop a lock, instead (using `iptables [-w|--wait]` option) wait for the ongoing execution to end.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering. First problem is that -w option doesn't help. It just never unlocks no matter how much seconds I pass. second one is that lslocks is not present in system. Third, the inum of /etc/xtables.lock is not present in /proc/locks.

Comment: 1) Then `iptables` or the executing app must be misbehaving. 2) Build it: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/lslocks.c 3) Your `iptables` binary seems to be the culprit. Use a custom built. // I have both binaries for `arm64` and I can share if needed.

Comment: Yes, share please.

Comment: https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=17248734326145737067, https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=17248734326145737068

Comment: Hello! Big thank. But it lslocks don't show any xtables locks. Does it means that it is not kernel lock?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin normally `iptables` won't take more than a few milliseconds to execute a command. So it's not very likely to run `lslocks` or `cat /proc/locks` within that very short period and see `iptables` holding a lock. As you've confirmed that both commands don't show that a lock is held on `/system/etc/xtables.lock`, that really means that a lock is not held. And that's why, as I already said, your `iptables` (or possibly some other related component) seems to be buggy. Can't be more specific unless I have the device in my hands.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for explanations, I'll digg deeper